# Verifying the output of an isolated layer in keras

Tags: keras, keras-layer

Is it possible to verify the output of

```
Cropping2D(cropping=((22, 0), (0, 0)), 
                     input_shape=resized_image.shape)
```

Without constructing and training a model? I.e. I just want to pass and image to Cropping and get and display the output image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is described in the Keras [FAQ](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer). To quote:

```
from keras import backend as K

# with a Sequential model
get_3rd_layer_output = K.function([model.layers[0].input],
                                  [model.layers[3].output])
layer_output = get_3rd_layer_output([X])[0]
```

This example assumes that your `Cropping` layer has index 3. You need to substitute this index with the correct number according to your model.

Comment: Thanks - I asume [X] in layer_output = get_3rd_layer_output([X])[0] would be the image?

Comment: Yes. Note that if you are using layers that utilize the learning phase, i.e. have different behavior for training and prediction, you need to supply the image and a 0/1 depending on the phase (1=learning phase, 0=eval. phase).

Comment: Ok, the snippet is a bit cumbersome and looks more like a workaround than a feature, but I tried it and it works.